# AngularJS orderBy directive not proper results

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of players and am trying to sort by grade first, then player name.  This is not the output I'm getting.  My understanding of the [`orderBy` filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy) is that an array of expressions is acceptable.

```
<li ng-repeat="player in players | orderBy:['player.grade.number','player.first_name']">
     {{ player.grade.number }} - {{ player.first_name }}
</li>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/h8Dlsmwi2mEqY9XzdRH7?p=preview

```
  $scope.players = [
    {
      "id":"91",
      "first_name":"Steve",
      "last_name":"Nickel",
      "grade":{
        "id":"7",
        "number":"7"
      }
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to start your string with `player`:

```
<li ng-repeat="player in players | orderBy: ['grade.number','first_name']">
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/QAmWayxwc5YXQEyPhbBI?p=preview